# OpenVPN error status: 2, and can't connect to internet while running openVPN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn

I recently installed openVPN and configured it with my client1.ovpn file:

```
client

dev tun

proto udp

remote 10.8.0.1 1194

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

key-direction 1

cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256

comp-lzo

verb 3

script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

my server.conf file:

```
port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key 

dh dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0

cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
auth SHA256

comp-lzo

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3
```

When I do the command

```
sudo openvpn --config client1.ovpn
```

I get this error in the terminal:

```
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL 
(OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, 
LZO 2.08
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth 
using INLINE static key file
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: 
Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: 
Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992-
>212992]
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed 
because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]10.8.0.1:1194
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 TLS: Initial packet from 
[AF_INET]10.8.0.1:1194, sid=640d1419 b8d9a3ee
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los 
Angeles, O=Fort-Funston, OU=Community, CN=Fort-Funston CA, 
name=Server, emailAddress=fasching.ryan@gmail.com
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Validating certificate key usage
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 ++ Certificate has key usage  00a0, expects 
00a0
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 VERIFY KU OK
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Validating certificate extended key usage
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server 
Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 VERIFY EKU OK
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los 
Angeles, O=Fort-Funston, OU=Community, CN=Ryan, name=Server, 
emailAddress=fasching.ryan@gmail.com
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' 
initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 256 bit message 
hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' 
initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 256 bit message 
hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 [Ryan] Peer Connection Initiated with 
[AF_INET]10.8.0.1:1194
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 SENT CONTROL [Ryan]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' 
(status=1)
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 PUSH: Received control message: 
'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 
208.67.222.222,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220,route 10.8.0.1,topology 
net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts 
modified
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options 
modified
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-
option options modified
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 WARNING: potential conflict between --remote 
address [10.8.0.1] and --ifconfig address pair [10.8.0.6, 10.8.0.5] -- 
this is a warning only that is triggered when local/remote addresses 
exist within the same /24 subnet as --ifconfig endpoints. (silence 
this warning with --ifconfig-nowarn)
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.15.65.1/255.255.255.0 
IFACE=wlp1s0 HWADDR=d0:57:7b:09:c7:c0
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt-
>did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 10.8.0.6 
peer 10.8.0.5
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.15.65.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.5
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 GID set to nogroup
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 UID set to nobody
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

I also cannot connect to the internet while openvpn is in use in the terminal. It isn't until I hit crtl+c before I'm able to connect to the internet again.

After ctrl+c I get these errors as well:

```
^CSat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 event_wait : Interrupted system call 
(code=4)
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 /sbin/ip route del 10.8.0.1/32
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 /sbin/ip route del 0.0.0.0/1
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 /sbin/ip route del 128.0.0.0/1
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 /sbin/ip addr del dev tun1 local 10.8.0.6 
peer 10.8.0.5
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 Linux ip addr del failed: external program 
exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 SIGINT[hard,] received, process exiting
```

I have been trying to find an answer to this question a lot on google already with no luck.

What is causing this error of " ERROR: Linux route add command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2"

as well as what is causing me to not be able to connect to the internet when using. Thanks.

Comment: `/sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.15.65.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists`...